# How to parse a bool expression in Haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell, functional-programming

I am trying to parse a bool expression in Haskell. This line is giving me an error: `BoolExpr <$> parseBoolOp <*> (n : ns)`. This is the error:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘[]’ with ‘Parser’
  Expected type: Parser [Expr]
    Actual type: [Expr]
```

```
-- define the expression types
data Expr
  = BoolExpr BoolOp [Expr]
  deriving (Show, Eq)

-- define the type for bool value
data Value
  = BoolVal Bool
  deriving (Show, Eq)

-- many x = Parser.some x <|> pure []
-- some x = (:) <$> x <*> Parser.many x
kstar :: Alternative f => f a -> f [a]
kstar x = kplus x <|> pure []
kplus :: Alternative f => f a -> f [a]
kplus x = (:) <$> x <*> kstar x 

symbol :: String -> Parser String 
symbol xs = token (string xs)

-- a bool expression is the operator followed by one or more expressions that we have to parse
-- TODO: add bool expressions
boolExpr :: Parser Expr
boolExpr = do
  n <- parseExpr
  ns <- kstar (symbol "," >> parseExpr)
  BoolExpr <$> parseBoolOp <*> (n : ns)

-- an atom is a literalExpr, which can be an actual literal or some other things
parseAtom :: Parser Expr
parseAtom =
  do
    literalExpr

-- the main parsing function which alternates between all the options you have
parseExpr :: Parser Expr
parseExpr =
  do
    parseAtom
    <|> parseParens boolExpr
    <|> parseParens parseExpr

-- implement parsing bool operations, these are 'and' and 'or'
parseBoolOp :: Parser BoolOp
parseBoolOp =
  do symbol "and" >> return And
    <|> do symbol "or" >> return Or
```

The boolExpr is expecting a `Parser [Expr]` but I am returning only an `[Expr]`. Is there a way to fix this or do it in another way? When I try pure (n:ns), `evalStr "(and true (and false true) true)"` returns `Left (ParseError "'a' didn't match expected character")` instead of `Right (BoolVal False)`

Answer (score 0):

The expression `(n : ns)` is a list. Therefore the compiler thinks that the applicative operators `<*>` and `<$>` should be used in the context `[]`, while you want `Parser` instead.

I would guess you need `pure (n : ns)` instead.

Comment: When I try pure (n:ns), ```evalStr "(and true (and false true) true)"``` returns ```Left (ParseError "'a' didn't match expected character")``` instead of ```Right (BoolVal False)```

Comment: @Lexi The grammar you've coded here is postfix and comma-separated. It accepts things like `false, true, true, false and`. In general: tokens in the input stream are expected to come in the same order as they appear in your `do` block.

Comment: That makes sense. I changed the comma to a space; is there a way to simultaneously allow bracket separation?

Comment: ```boolExpr :: Parser Expr
boolExpr = do
  symbol "("
  n <- parseExpr
  ns <- kstar (symbol " " >> parseExpr)
  op <- parseBoolOp
  symbol ")"
  BoolExpr op <$> pure (n:ns)``` is also returning the same thing even though I separated them by spaces.